# Call to undefined method Infusionsoft\Api\Rest\ContactService::addToGroup()

Tags: php, ubuntu, infusionsoft

I'm using https://github.com/infusionsoft/infusionsoft-php but when I try to apply tags for a contact I'm getting this error.

Someone knows something about it?

Comment: There is no addToGroup method in this file: https://github.com/infusionsoft/infusionsoft-php/blob/master/src/Infusionsoft/Api/Rest/ContactService.php

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. Void said there is no addToGroup() method in Rest Api. You should use [this](https://github.com/infusionsoft/infusionsoft-php/blob/a2197e66f92db53a9238f9324f31b7d998c39450/src/Infusionsoft/Api/ContactService.php) ContactService class instead of the one from Rest.